# Complex power of a load

Tags: power, three-phase, load

Simply, if there is a load that is 80kW and 95kVAR (inductive), can I then say that the complex power this load consumes is 80 + 95kVA or is there more to it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to study more carefully. KVA is the total magnitude of the complex power. The KVA is the square root of the sum of the squares of the kW and kVAR.

Comment: But is complex power not S = P + jQ? Were P is the 80kW and Q is 95kVars? I do not understand how S can be both S = P + jQ AND S = sqrt(P^2 + Q^2)

Comment: I see in the question that you wrote "load that is 80kW and 95kVAR" and then "the complex power this load consumes is 80 + 95kVA." If the first instance is correct, then the complex power is 80 kW + 95 kVAR. The apparent power is sqrt(P^2 + Q^2) kVA. This may have been a case of a writing kVA where you should have written kVAR.

Comment: @Zearia P and Q are vector quantities, with P along x-axis and Q along vertical.  So S (hypononeuse), P and Q form a right triangle called the power triangle.  So S = P + jQ equals |S| = sqrt (P^2 + Q^2)

Answer (score 0):

Complex power is: S = P + j*Q
but it is mistake saying "S = sqrt(P^2 + Q^2)"
what @Charles_Cowie said is: **|** S **|** = sqrt(P^2 + Q^2)
where |x| stands for the *magnitude* of the complex number "x"
Complex power is, in general, a complex number.
I suggest you to read more on complex numbers and AC power.